# OpenSolaris: unable to contact repository, connected to internet via proxy

Tags: networking, solaris, opensolaris

Opensolaris b134: unable to set packages catalog
this system is connected to internet via proxy, while this works on browser, how to make console/terminal aware?

user1@opensolaris134:~# pkg set-authority -O http://pkg.opensolaris.org/dev opensolaris.org
pkg set-publisher: Could not refresh the catalog for opensolaris.org
user1@opensolaris134:~# pkg image-update
pkg: 0/1 catalogs successfully updated:

Unable to contact valid package server
Encountered the following error(s):
Unable to contact any configured publishers. This is likely a network configuration problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pkg will respect the environment http_proxy variable.

```
# export http_proxy="http://proxyaddress:port"
# pkg ...
```